# How to do sudo edit in MC?

Tags: sudo, mc

Sometimes, when I use `mc` I need to edit file with `sudo`.

Is there a way to run `mcedit` (internal MC editor) or any other editor with `sudo` directly from MC (by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>)?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `mc` to run an external editor, then start it like this:

```
EDITOR=sudoedit SUDO_EDITOR=vim mc
```

(`$SUDO_EDITOR` should point to your favourite editor).  Then `mc` will run `sudoedit` when you press <kbd>F4</kbd> to edit files.